# Action bar custom style in my case

Tags: android, android-layout, android-intent, android-widget, android-actionbar

I am using Android native action bar. I would like to add my own drawable resource as the background of the action bar. So, I made a theme like following:

**res/values/themes.xml :**

```
<style name="Theme.MyStyle" parent="android:style/Theme.Holo.Light">
    <item name="android:background">@drawable/my_bg</item>
</style>
```

Then, in **AndroidManifest.xml** file I add this style to my application:

```
<application
        android:debuggable="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"

        android:theme="@style/Theme.MyStyle"
        >
   <activity ...>
   <activity .../>
   ...

</application>
```

**BUT**, the background drawable is applied **NOT ONLY** to action bar **BUT ALSO** to all fragments' content. why?

My 2nd question is, how to customize the **overflow** icon and the left-most "up" button on action bar??

Answer (score 6, accepted):

try

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <!-- the theme applied to the application or activity -->
    <style name="Theme.MyStyle" parent="@android:style/Theme.Holo">
        <item name="android:actionBarStyle">@style/MyActionBar</item>
        <!-- other activity and action bar styles here -->
    </style>

    <!-- style for the action bar backgrounds -->
    <style name="MyActionBar" parent="@android:style/Widget.Holo.ActionBar">
        <item name="android:background">@drawable/ab_background</item>
        <item name="android:backgroundStacked">@drawable/ab_background</item>
        <item name="android:backgroundSplit">@drawable/ab_split_background</item>
    </style>
</resources>
```

[customize the logo](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/ActionBar.html#setDisplayUseLogoEnabled%28boolean%29) using `setDisplayUseLogoEnabled(boolean)`

[More info](http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2011/04/customizing-action-bar.html)

Comment: yes, I followed the post there, and yield the problem ,and I ask here. I prefer more specific answer on my question instead to go back to the loop again. I have no problem with making custom style, the problem is that I added the style to my app in AndroidManifest.xml, but it applies to everywhere, not only action bar.

Comment: And I am not using tabs on my Action bar

Comment: I think your problem is in the property style parent. try applying it only to `"android:style/Widget.Holo.Light.ActionBar"`

Comment: try that last edit, and please consider the time and effort before downvoting. Thank you

Comment: Hi, your last edit is working. I see the reason, I should first put my action bar style into application style, then add to my app. Thank you! By the way, do I must use "Theme.Holo" as parent style for the styles applied to app?

Comment: The parent of the theme (Theme.MyStyle) applied in your app is the one that gets used when no style is defined to a concrete view, in other words, the default one. Use Holo, or the one you like the most